# How to select current selector and other selector

Tags: jquery

Bellow example working well but in this example I want to select "#btn-create" as "this" to hide it. Means when I click on "btn-create" button it should hide with given ID and Class.

```
$("#btn-create").click(function(){
   $("#btn-create, #add-goal-form, .custom-file-upload").hide();
   $(".add-goal-feedback, #btn-complete").show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try using `add()` function of jquery which will create a group of elements and then execute `.hide()` functionality on that group -

```
$(this).add(" #add-goal-form, .custom-file-upload").hide();
```

Comment: I think OP don't want to add the elements in `$(this)`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal `I want to select "#btn-create" as "this" to hide it`

Comment: one liner huh? nice! i see this implementation with `.add()` for first time, must be useful.